# breqn in journals

Tags: breqn, journal-publishing

I read the [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) manual, and I love the ideas in it (semantic markup for equations, automagic line breaks in math displays).

I would like to use it in my work (I am a research mathematician, so I mean mostly producing journal papers). However, I am a little bit worried about compatibility issues. Does anyone have experience with it in a similar context? Namely, what I would like to know is:

1. do math journals support it out of the box, or do I risk getting a nice message from them on the lines of "could you please re-format each and every formula in your paper before publication?"
2. are there any outstanding incompatibilities with commonly-used packages?
3. has the API changed a lot recently? I.e., will my collaborators with a slightly outdated TeX version still be able to compile the documents?

I hope that the question is in-topic here.

Comment: What is really needed is a way to convert the `breqn` broken equations to more standard amsmath stuff such as `align`, just before sending the file to a journal.  I need to think on how this could be done (`breqn` has been on my todo list for at least a year now). [likely future contributor to breqn here]

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch -- while conversion of `breqn` broken equations to `amsmath` structures is a great idea (and i hope you do come up with some workable thoughts as to how it might be done at least semi-automatically), to the best of my knowledge `breqn` is not rejected by ams journals.  (after all, its initial development was here.)  copyeditors may mark some of its results for adjustment, but i suspect that some must get through, although i have no concrete evidence either way.  `breqn` is definitely not on our "reject" list.  not perfect, but useful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for the information. This raises another natural question though: which packages are on your "reject" list? Shall I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Reasons I don't use breqn in my documents is that (1) I fear that different versions on my collaborator's installations change may the breaking of equation (I work with people still using `eqnarray`) (2) it occasionnally fails to find an appropriate line-break, and there is no way to force/suggest line-breaks (useful for copy-editors).  Both problems could be solved by providing an option for `breqn` to write a file with info about the line-breaks, and an option to use those line-breaks (I know this is a difficult problem).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch -- good reasons.  your idea of providing an option whereby an author or copyeditor can provide a hint for where they want a breakpoint is really good.  if you can figure out a way to do it, that would be great.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni -- the list of "reject packages" is too long to give in full, but here are some categories: anything that changes page dimensions or alignment; anything that changes the main text font; fonts that come only in metafont form if a comparable outline font is available; fancyhdr (conflicts with ams journal specs); caption packages (incompatible with ams caption style); anything unknown at ctan (unless provided by the author, and it doesn't conflict with ams style); makeidx (in ams classes); comment (all "private" comments must be removed, or we remove them here); obsolete packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that `breqn` is not perfect and if you want to achieve absolute beautiful mathematics, then you (a human being) should decide where an equation should and where it should not break.

1. I think, you would get a nice message from them on the lines of "could you please re-format each and every formula in your paper before publication?"
2. The only one I am aware of is that when `\TeXXeTstate=1` (enabling bidirectional typesetting in etex-based engines), with breqn you get absolutely different results (because the internal data structures built by TeX--XeT differ from those built by TeX, the typesetting of a document by TeX--XeT may therefore differ from that performed by TeX). As an example:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{breqn}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{dmath}[label={sna74}]
   \frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(k,h,0) +\frac{3(h-1)}{h}\right)
   +\frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(h,k,0) +\frac{3(k-1)}{k}\right)
   =\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{h}{k} +\frac{k}{h} +\frac{1}{hk}\right)
   +\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2h} -\frac{1}{2k},
   \end{dmath}
   \end{document}
   ```

   produces:

   [image]

   but

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{breqn}
   \TeXXeTstate=1
   \begin{document}
   \begin{dmath}[label={sna74}]
   \frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(k,h,0) +\frac{3(h-1)}{h}\right)
   +\frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(h,k,0) +\frac{3(k-1)}{k}\right)
   =\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{h}{k} +\frac{k}{h} +\frac{1}{hk}\right)
   +\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2h} -\frac{1}{2k},
   \end{dmath}
   \end{document}
   ```

   produces:

   [image]
3. I think your collaborators will be able to compile your documents with a slightly outdated `breqn` package as long as they use PDFTeX.